# .NET Core 6 - Analyzer 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Api.Analyzers.ApiConventionAnalyzer' threw an exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-6.0

When building my ASP.NET core Web API project, I'm getting the following warning:

```
1>CSC : warning AD0001: Analyzer 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Api.Analyzers.ApiConventionAnalyzer' threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' with message 'Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'target')'.
```

I'm using Rider to build the application. Any thoughts on what this error might mean? Or where to look for these "Value cannot be null" instances.

What does analyzer do, and how does it report these errors?

Comment: Build it with the `dotnet` cli and see if it works.

Comment: Are you using `ApiConventionTypeAttribute` ?

Comment: @YK1 no I'm not using `ApiConventionTypeAttribute`

Comment: Check if csproj has `IncludeOpenAPIAnalyzers` node set to `true.` Also check if all installed packages are up to date an match your runtime version.

Comment: `IncludeOpenAPIAnalyzers` is set to true, all packages are up to date.

Comment: I'm trying to understand why is that warning happening and where in the code is it happening. Is there any way of knowing?

Comment: @Will try setting `IncludeOpenAPIAnalyzers` to false. Warning is due to null error inside analyzer during build. The code is inside the analyzer which is invoked during build. if you will be able to share the repro - we can try to help you.

Answer (score 1):

The error was caused by returning null from a controller method expecting to return an ActionResult.

It’s a good idea to keep IncludeOpenAPIAnalyzers as true, this helps you with hints to add a response type corresponding to the helper method used. For example: BadRequest().

The error I received wasn’t too helpful when figuring out where was that warning being raised.